# Erdas - Export LUT Instead Of Real Values

Tags: ndvi, erdas-imagine

I am using Erdas 2022.
I have NDVI index of an imaging, and after creating it, the view shows a LUT which is not the original pixels, which is essentially the automatic stretching of the program.
I would like to export the viewed image, meaning the image with the LUT values themselves.

Any idea how to do it?

The following images show my goal: I want ti export a raster in which the pixels are 255 and not 0.525773.

Note that this question is for academic learning, and obviously not really relevant for real usages.

[image: NDVI image with inquiry]
[image: LUT value of the inquiry]